# Inquiries around a new number system

Tags: number-systems, hypercomplex-numbers

We can suppose that we will create a new number system with essentially two imaginaries that do not interact.  (Besides this, all quantities are taken to be integers)  For example, we have an $i_1$ and an $i_2$.  Then we could say

$$(a+b i_1)(c+d i_1) = ac + (ad + bc)i_1-bd$$

and, similarly for $i_2$:

$$(a+b i_2)(c+d i_2) = ac + (ad + bc)i_2-bd$$

**However**, for a system with $i_1$ AND $i_2$:

$$(a+b i_1+c i_2)(d + e i_1 + f i_2)=$$
$$(ad + ae i_1 + af i_2) + (bd i_1 - be + 0i_1i_2) + (cd i_2 + 0i_1i_2 -cf)$$

Above, the key thing to note is that $i_1\cdot i_2 = 0$.

**QUESTIONS**

I'm wondering if there is any idea or statement in math that says that I simply cannot do this.  Without having worked in general systems of numbers, I'm wondering what ideas I should know about when I try to create a system like this.

Can I create this system if my main purposes are to carry out addition, subtraction, and multiplication with these numbers?  Also, if I pose the additional constraint that all of these calculations are carried out modulo a prime, will this affect the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um, scratch the conclusions of my earlier answer. You get into more trouble than mere zero divisors:

$$1 = (-1)\cdot (-1) = i_1^2\cdot i_2^2 = (i_1 i_2)^2 = 0^2 = 0 $$

so everything collapses!

My observation that what you get is a quotient ring was technically right, but I failed to notice that the ideal $\langle X^2+1,Y^2+1,XY\rangle$ is just $\langle 1\rangle$ because $$1 = 1\cdot(X^2+1) - X^2\cdot(Y^2+1) + XY\cdot(XY) $$so the quotient ring you get is actually the zero ring.

---

If you drop the rule that $i_1\cdot i_2=0$ and instead just accept that your objects can also contain some multiple of $i_1 i_2$, then you stand a better chance.

In fact, if one decides that multiplication is not commutative and $i_1 i_2 = -i_2i_1$ but ordinary numbers commute with everything, then what one gets is exactly the quaternions!

Comment: Thank you very much for the fix.  +1  I will have to rethink the project I am working on.

Comment: But what if we drop associativity ? Does that imply that $a^2 b^2 $ can be different from $(ab)^2 $ ?

Answer (score 9):

**BEWARE. This answer is as wrong as it is possible for it to be without actually containing any technically false statements. See my other answer.** I'm leaving this up because the references to ring theory and quaternions are probably still helpful.

---

If $i_1 i_2=0$, then $i_1$ and $i_2$ are *zero divisors*, and neither of them can have multiplicative inverses (assuming other usual rules such as associativity and $0x=0$ hold), so what you get isn't a field.

You get even more zero divisors from the fact that $i_1$ and $i_2$ have the same square without being each other's negatives: $(i_1-i_2)(i_1+i_2)=i_1^2-i_2^2=0$.

It is, however, a *ring*, which allows you to do addition, subtraction and multiplication as you please. Division won't always be possible, like in the integers. There's a quite rich and well developed theory about such structures (look for "ring theory" or "commutative algebra"); what you have is a particular instance of one of the most common way of producing new rings, namely as quotients of polynomial rings. More specifically, in standard notation your ring can be constructed as $\mathbb R[X,Y]/\langle X^2+1, Y^2+1, XY\rangle$.

You can certainly use modular arithmetic as a base instead of $\mathbb R$. In standard notation that will give you $\mathbb Z[X,Y]/\langle p, X^2+1, Y^2+1, XY\rangle$. Note that you may get *yet more* zero divisors if $-1$ is already a square in $\mathbb Z$ modulo $p$.

---

(Ah, I just noticed that the question already specified that the base was the integers rather than $\mathbb R$. Then of course it is not a particular problem that you cannot always divide, because you can't do that even in $\mathbb Z$ itself. Note, however, that even *division with remainder* (which works well in $\mathbb Z$) won't have any nice generalization to any setting where there are zero divisors).

---

You might also look into *quaternions* which manages to be *almost* a field by having *three* imaginary units $i$, $j$, $k$, where the product of any two is either the third one or its negative. Then inverses always exist, but on the other hand multiplication is no longer commutative.

Comment: This is extremely informative - thank you very much!

Comment: Also octonions which have 7 imaginary units, but aren't associative.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the rule that $i_1 i_2=0$ but maintain commutativity, you will get [bicomplex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number).